# LibreOffice Calc Goal Seek does not work from Basic Macro

Tags: libreoffice, basic

I am trying to run a goal seek from a Calc Basic Macro.

```
Public Sub Goal_Seek()
  oVariableCell = detailSheet.getCellRangeByName("VariableCell")
  oFormulaCell = detailSheet.getCellRangeByName("FormulaCell")
  oTargetCell = detailSheet.getCellRangeByName("TargetCell")
  ThisComponent.seekGoal(oFormulaCell.CellAddress, oVariableCell.CellAddress, oTargetCell.getValue)
End Sub
```

When I run the Macro nothing is updated.  When I run Goal Seek from the spreadsheet menu Tools->Goal Seek and enter the same cells in the form, the goal seek functions normally.

My Macro is in My Macros-Standard-Module1. The Named ranges return the right cell addresses. What could be causing the goal seek to not update when called from the Macro?

Comment: I missed the first line of the sub when I cut and paste```detailSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(7)```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is I have to set the result myself when I call goal set from a Macro.  I should have guessed that. The new code is

```
  detailSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(7)
  oVariableCell = detailSheet.getCellRangeByName("VariableCell")
  oFormulaCell = detailSheet.getCellRangeByName("FormulaCell")
  oTargetCell = detailSheet.getCellRangeByName("TargetCell")
  oGoal = ThisComponent.seekGoal(oFormulaCell.CellAddress, oVariableCell.CellAddress, oTargetCell.getValue)
  oVariableCell.setValue(oGoal.Result)
End Sub
```